# Not work function in generic class

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I need to use this code for find user :

Main Project:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    var usersManagerService = StructureMapDefnation.Container.GetInstance<IUser>();

    var qUser = usersManagerService.Find(x => x.Username == "k" && x.Password == "k");
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

EFUesrService:

```
public class EfUserService : EfGenericService<User>, IUser
{
    public EfUserService(IUnitOfWork uow) : base(uow)
    {
    }
}
```

EFGenericService:

```
public class EfGenericService<T> : IGenericService<T> where T : class
{
    protected IUnitOfWork Uow;
    protected IDbSet<T> Entites;

    public EfGenericService(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        Uow = uow;
        Entites = Uow.Set<T>();
    }

    public T Find(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return Entites.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

it can not find any this, but this user "K" is exist in database.
What's the problem? How can I solve the problem?

Comment: K or k? Watch out for case-sensitivity.

Comment: FYI: imho is it nog a good idea to kick of db operations in the constructor of a form. Also, sharing the  Unit Of Work in a service can lead to many problems. There are way better repository implementations for EF but do not that a lot of people consider it an anti-pattern for EF.

Comment: Is the password of user `k` also `k`?

Comment: @mjwills yea . . .

Comment: You've connected directly to the database and verified that @kianoush ?

Comment: @mjwills connect directly it can not find any things

Comment: If you have connected directly to the database (through the database tooling rather than your app) and the data isn't there, how do you expect your app to find the (non-existent) data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things that you could try to diagnose the problem:

1) Let's loosen the criteria to ensure that there is any data in the database. This would check about the connectivity to the database is working fine.
Replace

```
var qUser = usersManagerService.Find(x => x.Username == "k" && x.Password == "k");
```

into something like

```
var qUser = usersManagerService.Find(x => x.Username == x.Username);
```

2a) If you have successfully get some data, then you could change the above to a bit more specific such as

```
var qUser = usersManagerService.Find(x => x.Username == "k");
```

ie: check if the Username is correct OR check if the password is correct.

2b) If you failed to get any data, then you would need to look at probably database connection, etc (and probably include more information as well as what you have tried that was unsuccessful).